# Setting mid-point of divergent colour ramp to zero using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, color-ramp

I am creating a number of rasters showing the standardised precipitation index (SPI) for a series of months for a specific region. To make the maps comparable, I need the midpoint of the colour scale I am using to be equal to zero for all maps, with blue colours related to wetter conditions (greater than 0) and red colours related to drier conditions (less than 0).

This can be done in ArcMap quite easily (by changing the value of the mid-point to zero in the "Advanced Labelling" pop-up on the symbology tab (as shown below), when the symbology is set to "stretched"), but is there a way to do this in ArcGIS Pro?

How I would do it in ArcMap:

[image]

Comment: +1. Never thought it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way in ArcGIS Pro. Symbology tab -> Advanced Labeling

**[image: strong text]**